# Determine $\lim_{n \to \infty} (2^{n+1} \sin(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}))$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I was able to calculate
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (2^{n+1} \sin(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}})) = \pi$$
using L'Hopital Rule, but how to get $\pi$ without it?

Answer (score 4):

Make the substitution

$$\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}} = \frac 1m\,$$

and use the limit

$$\lim_{m\to \infty}m\sin\left( \frac 1m\right) =1$$

---

Proof of this second notable limit. For $\alpha\in (0, \pi/2)$, we have the inequalities
$$\sin(\alpha) \le \alpha \le \tan(\alpha)\,.$$
Thus we do the following estimates
$$m\sin\left( \frac 1m\right) \le 1$$
and
$$m\sin\left( \frac 1m\right) = m\sin\left( \frac 1m\right) \frac{\cos\left( \frac 1m\right)}{\cos\left( \frac 1m\right)} = m\cos\left( \frac 1m\right)\tan\left( \frac 1m\right) \ge \cos\left( \frac 1m\right)$$
By squeeze theorem, one concludes.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, but how do you show that second limit?

Comment: It's one of those that go under the name **notable limits**. To prove it you can use that for $\alpha \in (0, \pi/2)$ you have the inequalities
$$\sin(\alpha) \le \alpha \le \tan(\alpha)\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

since $\sin  \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 2^{ n+1 } }  \right) \overset { n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \longrightarrow  } 0$ we can apply famous limit  $\lim _{ n\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \sin { n }  }{ n }  } =1$
$$\lim _{ n\to \infty  } \left( 2^{ n+1 }\sin  \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 2^{ n+1 } }  \right)  \right) =\lim _{ n\to \infty  } \frac { \sin  \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 2^{ n+1 } }  \right)  }{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2^{ n+1 } }  } \pi =\pi $$

Comment: I would appreciate an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Use *equivalents*:

Near $0$, we have $\sin u\sim u$, so
$$2^{n+1}\sin\frac\pi{2^{n+1}}\sim_\infty2^{n+1}\frac\pi{2^{n+1}}=\pi.$$

Comment: This makes most sense intuitively so I appreciate the answer a lot, however it doesn't feel "mathy". Maybe you could convince me that it's good enough?

Comment: It *is* a perfectly rigourous concept from analysis. Let me add the symbol $\sim$ does not mean ‘approximately equal to’,  but ‘is equivalent  near infinity to’ in a very precise sense. You can see  it defined at the beginning of the page of Wikipedia on [Asymptotic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis). With this notion you can get rid of spurious details in the computation of limits.